# Is it possible to use Ruby FFI to send a Ruby (C API) VALUE to a function?

Tags: c, ruby, ffi, narray

I'm currently trying to bridge `Numo::NArray` and `FFI`, so that an FFI `Pointer` can access the raw data in a `Numo::NArray` without having to [copy data through `String` like I do now](https://github.com/mike-bourgeous/mb-sound-jackffi/blob/b2ea2ec8aa4231f9a790ea7b2918af34e03f85cc/lib/mb/sound/jack_ffi.rb#L463) (thus causing GC churn and a wasted extra copy).

There is a C function exposed by `Numo::NArray` called `nary_get_pointer_for_read_write`, and this is [used already](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-fftw/blob/master/ext/numo/fftw/fftw.erb.c#L134-L141) by `Numo::FFTW`.  However, the parameter to this function is CRuby's internal `VALUE` type, and I haven't found a way to pass that `VALUE` using FFI.

Here's a *non-working* rough draft of what I'd like to try.  If this isn't possible, my next step might be writing another C extension gem to do the bridging, and after that maybe trying to PR a function to get an FFI pointer into the numo-narray project.

```rb
require 'numo/narray'
require 'ffi'

module NArrayFFI
  ffi_lib FFI::CURRENT_PROCESS
  attach_function :nary_get_pointer_for_read, [:RAW_RUBY_VALUE_IF_FFI_CAN_DO_THIS], :pointer
  attach_function :nary_get_pointer_for_write, [:RAW_RUBY_VALUE_IF_FFI_CAN_DO_THIS], :pointer
  attach_function :nary_get_pointer_for_read_write, [:RAW_RUBY_VALUE_IF_FFI_CAN_DO_THIS], :pointer
end

data = Numo::SFloat[1,2,3,4,5]
data_ptr = NArrayFFI.nary_get_pointer_for_read_write(data)
SomeOtherFFI.function_that_takes_pointer(data_ptr)
```

So, is it possible to pass the raw `VALUE` of a Ruby value to a function attached using FFI?

---

Here are references I've checked so far, that didn't have an answer, but might be useful to others with similar questions:

- [Ruby's C extension docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/extension_rdoc.html)
- [An open issue on Numo::NArray asking the same question](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray/issues/27)
- [The header definitions from Numo::NArray](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray/blob/e6fecbc72cf2a1b892554e0a6814767887b641cf/ext/numo/narray/numo/intern.h#L36-L47)
- [The source code of Numo::FFTW](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-fftw/blob/master/ext/numo/fftw/fftw.erb.c#L134-L141)
- [The Ruby FFI types documentation](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Types)